# Excel box and whisker chart: hiding inner points using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, boxplot

Does anyone know how to **hide the inner points** of a box or whisker chart?

This seems to be a hard one, I saw the same question multiple times but there is no description available at the time. I use the following code for generating multiple charts in a loop, works fine for me.

```
Set shp = wksData.Shapes.AddChart2(406, xlBoxwhisker, intLeft, intTop, intGraphWidth, intGraphHeight)
With shp.Chart
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = strLegend
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = wksData.Range(wksData.Cells(lngRowA, xPosAxis), wksData.Cells(lngRowZ, xPosAxis))
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(intR, intG, intB)
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(intR, intG, intB)
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).Format.Fill.Transparency = 0.8
    .ChartGroups(1).GapWidth = 20
    .Parent.Name = "Chart " & strTARGET
    .HasLegend = True
    .Legend.Position = xlLegendPositionBottom
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = strTARGET
    .Axes(xlValue).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Text = "[g/kg_fuel]"
    .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Text = strX
    .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True
End With
```

I already tried every possible way to generate this code via marcro recorder, but it doesn't show anything at all.

Comment: What are the _inner points_? Perhaps an image indicating what these are or a technical description if it exists?

Comment: Those are all of the points between the upper and lower fences (i.e., all points that are not outliers).

Answer (score 0):

The built-in Excel box plot is still not fully cooked:

- Format the vertical axis. You can change the minimum and maximum of
  the scale, but not the tick spacing.
- Drag the title to the left or right, oh wait, you can't.
- And lots more.

The VBA for the built-in Excel box plot is even more undercooked. Much of what you can do in the formatting interface cannot be accessed by VBA, including the inner point visibility.

You could build your own box plot which uses a regular Excel chart and some smoke and mirrors. See my tutorial at [Excel Box and Whisker Diagrams (Box Plots)](https://peltiertech.com/excel-box-and-whisker-diagrams-box-plots/).